# Formatting data in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-admin

Currently using flask-admin, my data is quite long per column, i'm wondering how to format it so each line goes underneath after a certain length.
So instead of

> FirstName
>
> johndoeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

transform it into this format.

> FirstName
>
> johndoeeeeee
>
> eeeeeeeeeeee
>
> eeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import textwrap

def _format_original_filename(view, context, model, name):
        formatted_original_name = textwrap.fill(model.original_name, 25)
        return formatted_original_name

column_formatters = {"original_name": _format_original_name}
```

this allowed me to wrap the string so it doesn't exceed the length view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `column_formatters` in Flask-Admin.

```
class ExampelModelView(ModelView):

    # ...

    def _format_first_name(view, context, model, name):

        formatted_first_name = procedure_to_format_first_name(model.first_name)

        return formatted_first_name

    column_formatters = {"first_name": _format_first_name}

    # ...
```

Comment: def _format_original_filename(view, context, model, name):
        formatted_original_name = textwrap.fill(model.original_name, 25)
        return formatted_original_name